# Grails clean doesn't work

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm using Grails -2.0.1 and when trying to run an app, I find a NoClassDefFoundError :

Error 2012-10-16 15:24:25,301 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NoClassDefFoundError occurred when processing request: [GET] /workstation/track/computerName/login/MacOSX/true/username

Could not initialize class workstation.server.TrackController. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error creating bean with name 'workstation.server.TrackController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class workstation.server.TrackController
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker

---

|   908 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

I couldn't figure out this error do I tried doing a grails -clean( in the hope of running again). Turns out the clean does not work

Error: plugin-list-grailsCentral.xml:29227:22: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. Also, did not find this XML in the grails directory.

Any clues anyone? Could anyone help me as to why the clean won't work?

Comment: namaste raghav, after following jake's advice, what happened?]

Comment: Try to excecute **grails clean** in **console**.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting .grails dir after the clean.  This can fix a lot of problems, especially when it comes to plugins.