# 'grails clean' reports `HTTPS Required (501)`

Tags: maven, grails, groovy

I have tried the following

1. Deleting .grails folder as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922215/grails-clean-doesnt-work).
2. In BuildConfig.Groovy,  changed `mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"` to `mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764749/requests-to-http-repo1-maven-org-maven2-return-a-501-https-required-status-an)
3. I have searched for `maven` and `http://repo` in my entire codebase and found it nowhere other than `BuildConfig.Groovy`. My `BuildConfig.Groovy` now contains

```
repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        //mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        //mavenLocal("../../lib/")
        mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
        mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        //mavenRepo "https://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "https://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "https://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```

I still get

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:pom:1.11.692 from/to mavenCentral (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): HTTPS Required (501)

when I run 'grails clean' and 'grails clean-all'.

I am missing something basic.

**Edit**

I am using a old version of Grails 2.3.7

Commenting mavenCentral() helped thanks @tim_yates

Comment: Letting people know the Grails version might help

Comment: Do you still have `mavenCentral()`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59948885/6509

Comment: @tim_yates yeah, removing mavenCentral helped. Still getting a few missing artifacts. I'll fix them and report back. Until then, please add a answer. Happy to mark it.

Comment: @tim_yates isnt there a solution without commenting mavenCentral? Since I am not able to find the location where mavenCentral is referring to http, nor am I able to add missing lib's after commenting mavenCentral

Comment: You have `mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"` which should replace, not augment, `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: In Grails 2.3.7 `mavenCentral()` will reference `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`, which is no longer valid (central requires https as of January 15 of this year).